# C++ solicitud por el miembro 'init’ en ‘mainRender’, el cual es del tipo ‘Renderer()’ que no es clase

Tags: c++, poo

hola estoy teniendo unos problemas con los métodos de una clase en mi programa, creo que se debe a la distribución en diferentes archivos de cabecera, quería saber en que casos particulares ocurre este error?

error: solicitud por el miembro 'init’ en ‘mainRender’, el cual es del tipo ‘Renderer()’ que no es clase.

Este es mi codigo en `predefs.cpp`:

```
#include "predefs.h"
#include "allegro.h"
#include "renderer/renderer.h"

void init(){
    Renderer mainRender();
    allegro_init();
    install_keyboard();
    mainRender.init();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Típicamente, ese tipo de error ocurre cuando se pretende acceder a un supuesto miembro de una entidad, cuando en realidad esa entidad no es una clase u objeto de alguna clase.

Por ejemplo:

```
int f();       // declaración de una función f, 
               // que no tiene parámetros 
               // y que devuelve int.

f.miembro = 5; // ¿Eh? 
               // no se puede llamar a un supuesto "miembro"
               // de f, porque f es una función
```

Comment: entiendo pero al parecer eso no sucede aqui, este es mi codigo en predefs.cpp:
<code>#include "predefs.h"
#include "allegro.h"
#include "renderer/renderer.h"

void init(){
    Renderer mainRender();
    allegro_init();
    install_keyboard();

    mainRender.init();

}</code>

Comment: sorry no se como hacer que aparezca el codigo en un bloque D:

Comment: @FacundoLorenzo Eso es entonces, como te decía: la línea `Renderer mainRender();` está declarando una función mainRender que no toma parámetros y que devuelve un objeto de tipo Render. Luego, cuando pones `mainRender.init()` el compilador no encuentra una función init() como miembro de la función mainRender() declarada más arriba. Quita los paréntesis en `Renderer mainRender();` para que quede `Renderer mainRender;` y estudia un poco.

Comment: madre mia, joder eso era entonces, no me di cuenta de los parentesis y creo que jamas lo iba a hacer, bueno muchas gracias seguire estudiando que veo que me falta mucho y ademas experiencia tambien me hace falta demasiado. saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Inicializaciones.

C++ tiene diferentes maneras de inicializar valores:

```
int a = 0.;    // Inicializamos un int con un literal double: estrechamiento.
int b = 0;     // Inicializacion "clasica".
int c(0);      // Inicializacion de estilo "funcional".
int d = int(); // Inicializacion con el valor por defecto de int (que es 0).
```

Todas esas inicializaciones son válidas e inicializan un entero, pero todas estas inicializaciones a veces además de confusas a la vista del programador pueden ser confusas a la vista del compilador:

```
int e();       // Esto es una declaracion de funcion no una declaracion de entero.
auto r = x(a); // Esto que es?
```

En el caso de `r` si `x` es una función el tipo de `r` será el tipo de retorno de la función `x` pero en el caso de que `x` sea un objeto `r` sera de tipo `x`.

En el caso de `e` y en el primer caso de `r` nos encontramos en lo que se conoce como "El [parseo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analizador_sint%C3%A1ctico) más vejatorio" (Most Vexing Parse en Inglés).

#### Inicializacion más vejatoria.

Las inicializaciones con paréntesis (`(` y `)`) pueden provocar el parseo más vejatorio en algunos contextos; este parseo es un tipo de ambigüedad sintáctica que el compilador puede resolver de formas "*inesperadas*", por ejemplo el siguiente código...

```
// Un int llamado numero_natural?
int numero_natural();
// Un float llamado numero_real?
float numero_real();
// Un short llamado otro_natural inicializado con short()?
short otro_natural(short());
// Un double llamado otro_real inicializado con double()?
double otro_real(double());
// Un objeto de tipo Renderer llamado mainRender?
Renderer mainRender();
```

... no es lo que parece, ninguna de las cuatro declaraciones corresponde a un [escalar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalar_(matem%C3%A1tica)) porque ¡son todo declaraciones de funciones!

```
// Funcion que devuelve int y no recibe parametros
int numero_natural();
// Funcion que devuelve float y no recibe parametros
float numero_real();
/* Funcion que devuelve short y recibe como parametro una funcion
   que devuelve short y no recibe parametros */
short otro_natural(short());
/* Funcion que devuelve double y recibe como parametro una funcion
   que devuelve double y no recibe parametros */
double otro_real(double());
// Una funcion que devuelve Renderer y no recibe parametros
Renderer mainRender();
```

#### Inicialización por llaves `{}`.

Para evitar este problema de ambigüedad (y algunos problemas de [estrechamiento de tipos](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~spl/Academic/ProgrammingLanguages/commentary/NarrowingAndWideningConversions.html)) a partir de C++11 se permite la inicialización con llaves (`{` y `}`):

```
int a = {0.};  // ERROR! Se estrecha un double en un int!
int b = {0};   // Inicializacion a 0.
int c{0};      // Inicializacion a 0.
int d = int{}; // Inicializacion al valor por defecto de int (que es 0).
int e = {};    // Inicializacion al valor por defecto de int (que es 0).

Renderer mainRender{} // Esto YA NO ES UNA FUNCION, es una inicializacion

auto r = x(a); // Llamada a funcion o construccion de objeto? quien sabe!?
auto s = y{a}; // Construccion de objeto sin ningun tipo de duda.
```

#### Solución.

A parte de la solución sugerida por [asdasdasd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/23397/2742) también puedes usar la inicialización por llaves para solucionar tu problema:

```
#include "predefs.h"
#include "allegro.h"
#include "renderer/renderer.h"

void init(){
    Renderer mainRender{}; // No mas vejaciones!!
    allegro_init();
    install_keyboard();
    mainRender.init();
}
```

Ten en cuenta que la inicialización por llaves es sólo posible con compiladores que soporten C++11 o superior.

Comment: "most vexing" - más irritante, más vergonzante, más prepotente, más embarazoso, ... _más vejatorio_. Ay, @PaperBirdMaster, qué elección...

Comment: @asdasdasd ¿*vexing* es un false friend?